# praising poetry about a saint

Tags: vocabulary

I was searching for a suitable word for a piece of writing composed for speaking  high of a pious man, such as a saint. I found one:  encomium. Can we use the word 'encomium' for a piece of poetic writing praising a saint?

Comment: encomium can be used for any writing that praises someone.

Comment: So you mean poetry praising a saint?

Answer (score 1):

The word means a piece of writing that uncritically praises or glorifies someone or something.  You could use it for a poem to praise or glorify a saint.

But be aware that this is an *extremely* rare word. Most native speakers (including me) will not know what it means, and would have to look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: *Encomium* is a word a high-school student in the US might encounter in standardized university entrance tests. It's a word you are unlikely to see in the newspaper, but if you read books about poetry and literary history you'll definitely run into it sooner or later.

Comment: Searching google ngrams suggests it is almost only used in the context of classical (Greek and Latin) rhetoric. I doubt many sixth form students would come across this word. This may reflect differences in education between the UK and US.

Comment: accolade, encomium, are definitely A level/SAT level words. No use trying to stir the AmE/BrE pot.

Comment: "accolade" is relatively common word.  Encomium is exceedingly rare.  I struggle to find an example of it used, except as the title of particular Greek or Latin poems,  or parodies of them.  I'd be interested if you can find a book that is suitable for 16-18 year old students that uses this word as a common noun.